# Where does a logger goes in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

To which layer does the logger belongs in DDD?

Comment: +1 to offset the asinine down vote.  Define "layer"?  Seriously?

Comment: Isn't it a cross-cutting concern?

Comment: @qstarin: The question was unclear. I had to decipher DDD from the tags and got left with no other clueue. Maybe the people who know the answer will recognize the question, but that's worthless for future reference. Read the tooltip of the minus button: "This question is __unclear__ or not useful".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What would we want to log in DDD?

Important **events** that occur, of course.

The Logger itself is a service of the infrastructure.  Bridging the domain and the logger can occur in an event handler.

Logging fits well inside of **event handlers** and when placed there it creates a very nice separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements for a logger are, but if you are using it for creating an audit trail to track changes to an aggregate then it should go into the repository layer.